# Change Windows font size when laptop is docked

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dpi, docking-station

I just upgraded from a tower to a laptop at work.  Hooray for working from home.

Windows 7's default font size (125%) looks good on my 140dpi laptop display (15.4" 1920x1080), but it looks rather pre-school on my 94dpi main monitor (24" 1920x1200).

Is there any way to have Windows automatically change the font size when I dock my laptop?

Comment: I'm looking into using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) scripting with WMI for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to try this, but you can go into Control Panel and select "Appearance and Personalization" and go to "Fonts" then "Font Settings." In that window there is an option for creating shortcuts for your font settings. You can try that.

It may not be automatic, but it's the closest thing, otherwise, you might just have to change it manually every time you dock your laptop.

Comment: It looks like that option is more for shortcuts to font files in the file system, not for shortcuts to font settings.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Windows 7 answer, but Windows 8.1 has options to scale per-screen:

[How to use different scaling for every monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/629376/how-to-use-different-scaling-for-every-monitor)

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx