# Is there a way to specify separate scaling factors for multiple monitors in Windows 8.1?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, display-settings, scaling

I have a Samsung Series 7 Ultra laptop with the latest update to Windows 8.1. I am using an additional digital monitor with the same nominal resolution (1080p) as the laptop, but much larger in size (13'' laptop vs 22'' external monitor). The two screens are set up to "Extend these displays", meaning that my desktop spans both of them showing different content.

I am aware of two option for controlling the size of elements on the screen:

1. Choose one scaling level for all my displays
2. Let the system scale displays while maintaining the physical size of on-screen elements (thereby changing their nominal pixel resolution when I move them from one screen to another)

If I choose option 1, I am able to specify a scaling level but item appear either two small or two big on one of the two monitors. I have no way to change the ratio of the scaling factor between the two screens.

If I choose option 2, I can specify how large item appear for both, but again I have no control over the ratio of the scaling factors for the two monitors. While the auto-selected ratio provides for similar size of elements on the two screens, it results in visibly blurry text in most software on one or both screens.

A similar question was asked several moths ago:
[How to use different scaling for every monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/629376/how-to-use-different-scaling-for-every-monitor)

However, there has been at least one major update to Windows 8.1 since, targeting screen scaling among other things (Windows 8.1 Update for x64-based Systems -- KB2919355).

My question following this update is:

Is it now possible on Windows 8.1 with KB2919355 installed, via the GUI or registry, to directly specify percent scaling separately for each attached monitor?

Comment: Have the same issue. Best info so far is this: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx So it's either automatic or the same. Just that automatic does it wrong for me...

Comment: I have [a similar problem](http://superuser.com/q/820370/16858), and suspect it is down to poorly set up monitor 'drivers'.

Comment: Best solution is 2 video cards if u have another slot..

Answer (score 1):

It's still not possible for now.

I created [a feature suggestion on official windows uservoice forum](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6583844-allow-manually-set-dpi-for-every-monitor) a few months ago, feel free to vote for it, and let's hope Win 10 will fix this.

Comment: Any news on this?