# Is there a way to set (or disable) DPI scaling for individual monitors (Windows 8.1)

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, dpi

I have three screens connected:

- Two 1920x1200 screens that I do not want DPI scaled.
- 1 4K screen that I do want to scale.

Currently, if I set a 1920x1200 screen to be my "main" display, and then set the scaling to the recommended setting, the 1920's are fine, the 4K is blurry (this also has a side effect of putting the clock, etc on a 1920 screen, which is not in the middle).

If I do the inverse, the 4K is fine, the 1920's are blurry on apps that are DPI aware (Chrome looks fine - Explorer, Outlook, etc. do not).

Is there a way to configure this via Windows or with a third party tool?

Comment: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx

Comment: Windows will automatically choose the zoom level for each monitor based on its dpi value, so don't select "let me choose one scaling level for all displays" http://superuser.com/questions/629376/how-to-use-different-scaling-for-every-monitor

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc - I haven't selected that option "Let me choose one scaling level for all of my displays" is not selected.

Comment: Agree that option doesn't work the way t's supposed to. Was hoping to find a 3rd party tool to manage this until MS fix it up.

Comment: I have [a similar problem](http://superuser.com/q/820370/16858), and suspect it is down to poorly set up monitor 'drivers'.

Comment: Possible duplicate question...http://superuser.com/questions/740669/is-there-a-way-to-specify-separate-scaling-factors-for-multiple-monitors-in-wind

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible, but hopefully someone will make a tool soon. Until then consider using multiple of the same monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found that Windows 10 includes the feature to set an individual scale factor for each monitor. So the issue will be resolved by upgading to Windows 10 when it is released or to try the currently available Technical Preview for Windows Insiders.

Comment: Are you really absolutely positive you can do this? In previous versions of the Technical Preview the scaling settings were the same as on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yes, it works. I am running a setup with three monitors set to 125%, 100% and 200% right now. This is on Windows 10 Build 10130. I know that in some of the previous builds there were two different versions of the display settings control panel which was confusing as the modern one of them supported the individual scaling and the classic control panel did not. However if you use the modern display settings control panel the scaling can be set individually per monitor.