# Fixing Dell XPS 12 High DPI scaling

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, resolution

I have a Dell XPS 12 with a 12.5" Full HD display, extended onto an external 24" WUXGA display. With the default scaling, text on the Dell screen is unreadably small at normal reading distances, while text on the external 24" is slightly over large.

I have tried changing the scaling, but unlike the displays at [Windows 8.1 DPI Scaling Enhancements](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements/), everything I try scales the both screens equally.

Since there appears to be no workable answer to [How to use different scaling for every monitor?](https://superuser.com/q/629376/16858) I am left with trying to figure out why my Dell XPS 12 screen doesn't scale properly in the first place.

The 24" monitor correctly identifies itself as a Dell U2412M, but the Laptop display shows itself as "Mobile PC Display" in the Screen Resolution control panel and "Generic PnP Monitor" in the Monitor tab of the Advanced settings.

So, is there any way I can fix the baseline scaling of a"Generic PnP monitor" or am I stuck with assuming that the built in panel is a 96 dpi display, which it is closer to 180 dpi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use different scaling for every monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/629376/how-to-use-different-scaling-for-every-monitor)

Comment: Sadly I think it is a duplicate @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 such a shame that there is no answer there either.

Comment: Although I voted to close myself after seeing your comment @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've now completely rewritten the question such that it is no longer a duplicate. This now goes to the heart of my problem.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're not cloning the displays instead of extending the desktop between them are you?

Comment: Yup, just edited to make that clear, thanks @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007.