# How to choose one scaling level for all displays in windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, resolution, scaling

In Windows 10, one selects scaling level for each monitor separately. In Windows 8.1, you could disable that by checking `Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays` (screenshot in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/629376)). How can you do that in Windows 10?

**Background:** I have a laptop, which I occasionally connect to various projectors / big monitors in various conference rooms. Some of these projectors have suggested scaling values of 150% which I don't like. Currently I mark each new projector as 100% (which requires logoff/logon to take effect), and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the **Control Panel**
2. Head to **Hardware and Sound** and then **Display**
3. Click on the *Set a custom scaling level* link in the text.

[image: control Panel - Display - Win 10]

4. Adjust and apply until satisfied.

[More info](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-dpi-scaling-level-displays-change-windows-10-a.html#option2)

Comment: Yep, this works. 
Note just setting the custom scaling level to 100% (and signout+signin) didn't change anything - I had to set to 125%, signout+signin, change back to 100%, signout+signin, and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a custom scaling level as described [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-dpi-scaling-level-displays-change-windows-10-a.html#option2). No idea if that sticks for new displays but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Do no provide only a link in an answer, you should post the relevant information in blackquoted text because links could eventually expire.